# Slashed characters in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, characters

In LaTeX there is a `slashed` package which will put a nicely centered slash through an arbitrary symbol - the `\not` command provides an off-center slash on most symbols.  How can I do this in ConTeXt?  I need this in math mode, so that, for example:

```
\definecharacter notx {\buildtextaccent\textslash x}
```

gives me a nice text slashed x, but not a math one.

Thanks!

Comment: The `slashed` package should work out the box in ConTeXt.

Comment: I tried using the slashed package, but it gave me lots of error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked it out!  Here's my solution:

```
\usesymbols[was]

\def\Not #1{\wasy@over{/}{#1}}
```

Then in math mode:

```
$\Not{x}$
```

provides a properly slashed x.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to your question by clicking the tick mark underneath the vote counter. That will move it off the list of unanswered questions. You might also want to have a look at your other questions and see if there are answers that you could accept, which would increase the answerers' (and your) reputation.